# getting a file named the youngest %Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S file from ftp server

Tags: python, ftp

I'm newbie with python programming that's y i'm facing a lot of problems.

My idea is to make two script named script 1 and script2.
The first one take care of copying `%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S.txt` files from a server to a specific directory, while the second should take the youngest `%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S.txt` file,
open it and get data from this file to store it to a DB  and finally delete the file from server.

As I'm newbie I started writing code 
the problem is how can I open the file and make a variable named old_file to store file name
then convert this name into a  string used later for testing.

This is what i wrote for now:

```
import os 

f = open ('%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S')
filenamestr = str(f.name)
spli = filenamestr.split("_")
filenameint = int (spli[0]+spli[1]+spli[2]+spli[3]+spli[4]+spli[5])
print filenameint #this just for test

old_file = 'really idont know what i have to insert here'
if ((filenameint-old_file)>= 0):
    commands here
else:
    commands.
```

thx in advance

laaroussi salah

Comment: Do you mean there will be multiple files, each of which has a filename corresponding to a date format? Your code is trying to open a file with that literal name.

Comment: jonrsharpe, that's exactly what i mean, the server will receive  %Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S.txt files let's say for every minute. let's say for exemple the first file : 2014_05_15_22_11_53.txt the second will have as a name 2014_05_15_22_12_53.txt so have to get data from each file and delete it after getting data.

Comment: So how does your code even attempt to do that? You need to look at [`os`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#files-and-directories) and [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime).

Comment: this is exactly my biggest problem. i have to get the file name

Comment: maybe i can use the glob but it will list all file with the same extension, not the last file received

Comment: So parse the file names with the other link and use that to determine the order. You need to have code that at least attempts what you're describing before it's on-topic here.